# Why is a machine of type i440fx created when I specify q35 and how do I get q35 to work?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virsh

I need to create a Windows VM with a Q35 machine type. However, in spite of specifying q35, and i440fx machine is created.

created with:

```
sudo virt-install \
--name wintest \
--boot uefi \
--ram 32768 \
--graphics spice \
--machine q35 \
--features kvm_hidden=on \
--hostdev 0a:00.0,address.type=pci,address.multifunction=on \
--machine pc \
--vcpus 4 \
--os-type windows \
--os-variant win10 \
--network bridge=br0 \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--disk /home/boss/Downloads/Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso,device=cdrom \
--disk /home/boss/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.164.iso,device=cdrom \
--disk path=/home/boss/testVM/wintest.img,bus=virtio,size=60
```

resulting domain XML:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='5'>
  <name>wintest</name>
  <uuid>02288584-0660-4478-99b0-0189cc4567ff</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>33554432</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>33554432</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-3.1'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/wintest_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state='on'/>
    </kvm>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>EPYC-IBPB</model>
    <vendor>AMD</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tsc-deadline'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tsc_adjust'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='cmp_legacy'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='perfctr_core'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='virt-ssbd'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='monitor'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='svm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='topoext'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/boss/Downloads/Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/boss/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.164.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/home/boss/testVM/wintest.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:52:9a:ef'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet1'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <driver name='vfio'/>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x0a' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+1000:+1000</label>
    <imagelabel>+1000:+1000</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

There are a few errors from the command line during creation, but I think they are probably irrelevant, but here they are:

```
Starting install...
Allocating 'wintest.img'                                    |  60 GB  00:00     

(virt-viewer:23811): GSpice-WARNING **: 03:02:45.002: PulseAudio context failed Connection refused

(virt-viewer:23811): GSpice-WARNING **: 03:02:45.002: pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

(virt-viewer:23811): GSpice-WARNING **: 03:02:45.126: Could not create org.gnome.SessionManager dbus proxy: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=53385a97d6e04bd9aa29b8b8cb510ddb --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

(virt-viewer:23811): GSpice-WARNING **: 03:02:45.126: Warning no automount-inhibiting implementation available
Domain creation completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you inadvertently specified `--machine` twice.

```
--machine q35 \
--features kvm_hidden=on \
--hostdev 0a:00.0,address.type=pci,address.multifunction=on \
--machine pc \
```

Remove the inappropriate line containing `--machine pc \`.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. I think you pointed that out before.